# Sinusoidal acf plot

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to fit an ARMA model to a real data series.

This is a plot of the acf. So I am really confused.

Does this imply some sort of unit root?

[image]

Comment: Have you done an augmented Dickey-Fuller test? You can statistically check for unit roots

Comment: This suggests both seasonality and a unit root. What's the variable? WHat does the PACF look like?

Comment: @Nitin. Yes I did augmented DF test and it indicated stationarity which seemed odd.

Comment: @Glen_b  the pacf indicates AR(2)

Comment: Surprising - I expected to see something further out as well. By the look of it, the coefficients for an AR(2) must be close to the triangular non-stationarity boundary.

Answer (score 2):

> This suggests both seasonality and a unit root.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @Glen_b as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is by far what I know:

This type of trend means that you have a seasonality at the positive and negative peaks of the sinusoidal ACF. Since the ACF is going toward 0 it means that you are likely dealing with an AR model. Try to use SARIMA to account for the seasonality of the time series.