# What could indicate autocorrelation from the below correlogram?

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, stationarity

[image]

I would like to ask you a question about autocorrelation from my table. Autocorrelation slows down and then it is up and again slows down. It could indicate non-stationarity of time series?

Answer (score 0):

Acf reminds cosine, so your autocorrelation function looks like the one from sine wave.

Check here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518206/finding-the-autocorrelation-of-a-sine-wave

also here can be informative for you:
[Sinusoidal acf plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315368/sinusoidal-acf-plot)